# Interchanging limit and integral and partial sums involving characteristic function

Tags: integration

Let
\[
B_{N}(t) \equiv \sum_{k \leq t} a(n)\chi_{A_{N}}(n),
\]
where $A_{N}$ is some subset of $\mathbb{N}$ such that
$A_{N} \to \mathbb{N}$ as $N \to \infty$ and
$\chi_{A_{N}}(n)$ is the characteristic function
for $A_{N}$.

Suppose that the integral
\[
\int_{A}^{\infty} \frac{B_{N}(t)dt}{t^{s}}
\]
($A > 0$) converges absolutely for each $N$ and the limit
\[
\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{A}^{\infty} \frac{B_{N}(t)dt}{t^{s}}
\]
exists.

Then can we say that 
\[
\lim_{N \to \infty}\int_{A}^{\infty} \frac{B_{N}(t)dt}{t^{s}}
= \int_{A}^{\infty} \frac{B(t)dt}{t^{s}},
\]
where
\[
B_{N}(t) \equiv \sum_{n \leq t} a(n)\chi_{\mathbb{N}}(n)
= \sum_{n \leq t} a(n) \quad ?
\]

This problem has attracted me recently.

If the answer to this problem is positive, then
it seems that we can regard 
the limit
\[
\lim_{N \to \infty}\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n) \chi_{A_{N}(n)}}{n^{s - 1}}
\]
as 
\[
\sum_{n \geq 1} \frac{a(n)}{n^{s - 1}}
\]
which is very good for some reason.

Any idea would be really appreciated.

Comment: In the definition of $B_N$, what is $n$?

Comment: It's possibly a typo, which could be $n<t$ under the summation.

Comment: These sorts of questions almost always boil down to an application of the dominated convergence theorem, monotone convergence theorem, etc.  You're probably going to need some additional conditions on the coefficients $a(n)$; statements like this are usually not true in full generality.

Comment: I agree. After all, even if $\lim_{N \to \infty} \int_{A}^{\infty}B_{N}(t)t^{-s}dt =  \int_{A}^{\infty}B(t)t^{-s}dt$, there is a problem of interchanging limits when I try to analyze the integral $\int_{A}^{\infty}B(t)t^{-s}dt$ by $\int_{A}^{T}B(t)t^{-s}dt$.